# HGRCPATH kept in /etc/sudoers, yet ignored by hg?

Tags: sudo, configuration, mercurial

I'm trying to follow the directions [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TrackingEtcEtc) under "sudo and multiple users".  I believe I managed to modify `/etc/sudoers` correctly enough (by adding `Defaults :me env_keep += "HGRCPATH"` at the beginning of the defaults section, but later cutting `:me` because sudo was giving me parse errors) because I get this:

```
[me /]$ su
Password:
[root /]$ echo $HGRCPATH
/home/me/.hgrc
```

However, when I try to actually use `hg`, I run into trouble:

```
[me /]$ sudo hg commit -m "Initial check-in."
abort: no username supplied (see "hg help config")
```

Indeed:

```
[me /]$ sudo hg debugconfig --debug | grep read
read config from: /usr/etc/mercurial/hgrc
read config from: /etc/mercurial/hgrc
read config from: /etc/mercurial/hgrc.d/mergetools.rc
read config from: /root/.hgrc
```

Why does `hg` appear to be ignoring $HGRCPATH and looking in `/root/.hgrc` rather than `/home/me/.hgrc`?

**UPDATE**

Here are the non-commented lines of `/etc/sudoers`:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers | grep '^[^#]'
Defaults env_keep += "HGRCPATH"
Defaults    requiretty
Defaults   !visiblepw
Defaults    always_set_home
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
me     ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

Comment: Please copy-paste your complete `/etc/sudoers` file. Maybe there's another directive there that applies, or maybe you have things in the wrong order.

Comment: Regarding my aside about chopping ` :me`, I figured out there shouldn't be a space: `Defaults:me ...` parses without errors.

Comment: I've updated the wiki I had been following to reflect that and to include Gilles' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Defaults env_keep += "HGRCPATH"
> Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
> ```

That second line resets `env_keep`. Either stick to `+=` or move the `=` line before any `+=` line.

Comment: This didn't jump out at me until your answer had me look at the output you asked for, which I didn't actually look at initially--I had been looking at the config file itself with all the comments, which spread things out and made it a bit less intuitive.  Thanks for your help, now I see it clearly :)